# Bold word in string if regex pattern matches

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, dom

**Idea:**

I want to highlight words of a string if they are typed in with curly braces (like "Lorem {Ipsum} Sit Dolor"). If they match, font-weight: bold should be applied.

**Approach so far:**

```js
var final = [];
var regExp = /([^{]*?)(?=\})/;
var string = document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerHTML;
wordArray = string.split(/\s+/);

for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    if (regExp.exec(wordArray[i])) {
        final.push(wordArray[i]);
    }
}
console.log(final);
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="myParagraph">This is a test string with a {bold} text. Lets {see} if this works</p>
</body>
```

Now I got my words I need to highlight with CSS and would do a jQuery.each with jQuery.css() but I'm not sure now how apply the style and 'refresh' the DOM automatically.

Comment: what about `final.push("<b>" + wordArray[i] + "</b>")`

Comment: Yes, thats better than using jQuery and CSS but my problem is how I can render the paragraph as a whole => <p id="myParagraph">This is a test string with a <b>bold</b> text. Lets <b>see</b> if this works</p>.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gj51tbcn/ but looks like you've a shorter and better option already ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit using [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and directly writing to the innerHTML of the element.

The Regex is also a little different as I assume you don't want to keep the curly braces in the output, so they are not kept in a capture group.

In terms of the styling, you could wrap the element in a span with a specific class, but I just used the native `strong` tag as that is semantically correct and has the style you are after by default.

```js
function bolderize(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/{([^}]+)}/gm, '<strong>$1</strong>')
}
bolderize(document.getElementById('myParagraph'))
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="myParagraph">This is a test string with a {bold} text. Lets {see} if this works lol</p>
</body>
```

Comment: FYI: The `/m` modifier is redundant here and may be safely removed.

Comment: Really? it's using innerHTML to get the text content, which could have new lines in it if used on a different element with different content.

Answer (score -1):

To apply bold fonts with CSS, define a CSS class like this in a CSS style sheet file.

```
.BeBold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Then, use JavaScript to replace the identified string section framed by curly braces to a string that includes span tags that also uses the new CSS class.

So this ...

```
{lpsum}
```

... changes to this ....

```
<span class="BeBold">{lpsum}</span>
```

You can also remove the curly braces, if you wish, during this substitution.